# Complex form fourier series of a sum of e

Tags: fourier-series

The heart of the problem is finding a fourier series in its complex form for:

$\displaystyle\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-4|t-k|}$

The form I know of is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} C_ne^{ikt\omega}$

My problem is that this is not a periodic and I dont know how to proceed.

A direction will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your function is in fact periodic with period $1$. Use the substitution $\ell = k-1$ in the calculation $f(t + 1) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-4 |(t+1) - k|} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-4 |t - (k-1)|} = \sum_{\ell= -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-4 |t - \ell|} = f(t)$. On each compact intervall your series converges uniformly. You can thus calculate the Fourier coefficients by interchaning the integral and the sum in $\int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2\pi inx} dx$.

Comment: Nice spot. Thanks. But how do you integrate over this sum with absolute value?

Comment: For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ the sign of $t-k$ is fixed for $t \in [0,1]$. This should allow you to calculate each term individually.

Comment: That is a good explanation. Thank you